# Reminds And Send me Email

Tags: reminders

I'm trying to develop a reminds app. This code is a framework that I need. I have 3 spreadsheets, and I intend, in each spreadsheets, monitor deadlines. When the deadline is less than five days, it should send an e-mail. It has worked well in the following manner:

```
function sendEmails() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('2016.2');
   var clientesInfo = sheet.getRange(2, 7, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();

    //Data de hoje na coluna G2;
   for (var i = 0; i < clientesInfo.length; i++) {
     if (clientesInfo[i][1] < 5 && clientesInfo[i][1] >= 0 ) {
      MailApp.sendEmail("roger@tr.br", "Atenção! Prazo se esgotando(Isso é apenas um teste)", "Verifique tarefas que estão próximas de vencer, em: https://g.gl/plgTRU7");

    } `enter code here`
  }
 }
```

But I want now that that same code, I can monitor multiple spreadsheets, spreadsheet 2016.2. How should I do? Create multiple ifs? What if I have 100 sheets? Will be 100 ifs?

Comment: Could you please provide some more information and add more tags in order to address a bigger audience since `reminders` tag has two followers only.

Comment: The basic answer is to make a List<string> of spreadsheet names, then iterate over that getting "clientesInfo" Range (ie, the rest of your code falls inside a "foreach (string file in spreadsheetNames) { //rest of your code in here// } ". It's up to you to decide though how you are going to pull all the spreadsheet names in the first place, which is why I can't give you a definite answer.